# How to use Placeholder value as a title of the text box when user clicks on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to use the placeholder value as the title when user click on the text box.
For example in this image [Image One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au4IU.png) the placeholder value is "Email or phone" when user clicks on it it becomes the title of this text box as shown in second image here [Image Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2Oi1.png) . If you didn't understand correctly then please go to gmail.com (New Look Of Sign In) when you click on the text box the placeholder value goes top and when you click outside, that value becomes the placeholder. I want exactly that functionality but I'm unable to do it.
Help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this

HTML Code

```
<div>
  <input type="text" class="inputText" />
  <span class="floating-label">Email or phone</span>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
input:focus ~ .floating-label,
input:not(:focus):valid ~ .floating-label{
  top: 8px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.inputText {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
}

.floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 20px;
  top: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
```

Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/60Lfj34s/

Comment: Hi Paresh Maghodiya,

Comment: Yes, any other help you need

Comment: Thanks bro for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

I tried for a long time to come up with a pure CSS solution to this, but there is a real issue in that the `<input>` element will not take a `::before` pseudo-element, so you cannot use (for example):

```
input:focus::before {
content: attr(placeholder);
}
```

So here is a javascript solution instead:

```js
var myInput = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
var myPlaceHolder = myInput.getAttribute('placeholder');

function addInputLabel() {

if (document.getElementsByClassName('my-label').length < 1) {
        var myLabel = document.createElement('div');
        myLabel.textContent = myPlaceHolder;
        myLabel.classList.add('my-label');
        document.body.insertBefore(myLabel, myInput);
    }
}

myInput.addEventListener('keypress', addInputLabel, false);
```

```css
.my-label {
height: 16px;
line-height: 16px;
font-size: 11px;
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Placeholder Text" />
```